# linq to sql querying a tag system - toxi

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I've set up a tagging system

I belive it is the "toxi" solution with the following tables:

**Books**[id,author, title] *has many-to-many relationship with*

**Tags**[id, tagName]

**BookHasTag**[id, bookId, tagId] *junction-table*

using linq-sql I want to:

- select the top 20 most popular tags and have their count with it
- given a books id, get all the info about the book, including tags associated with it
- a list of all books that are associated with a particular tag

Please can you help, I know it's a little cheeky, and I know SO usually like to see you have made an effort, but for the sake of brevity i'm leaving out my failed attempts.

Comment: What does your class model look like? In other words, do you for instance have a `Book` class with a `Tags` property returning a list of `Tag`-objects, and vice verca a `Tag` class with a `Books` property returning a list of `Book`-objects?

Comment: No, the Book Class has BookHasTag property, and the Tag class has BookHasTag

Comment: I would suggest you include the relevant parts of your code. That makes it so much easier coming up with a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want something like this:

*select the top 20 most popular tags and have their count with it*

```
var lsTags=(
        from tag in db.Tags
        select new
        {
            tag.id,
            tag.tagName,
            NbrOfTags=
                (
                    from hasTags in db.BookHasTag
                    where hasTags.tagId==tag.id
                    select hasTags.id
                ).Count()
        }
    ).OrderByDescending(a=>a.NbrOfTags).Take(20).ToList();
```

*given a books id, get all the info about the book, including tags associated with it*

```
var bookId=1;
var lsBooksWithTags=(
        from book in db.Books
        where book.id==bookId
        select new
        {
            book.id,
            book.author,
            book.title,
            Tags=(
                    from bookHasTag in db.BookHasTag
                    join tags in db.Tags
                        on bookHasTag.tagId equals tags.id
                    where bookHasTag.bookId==book.id
                    select new
                    {
                        tags.id,
                        tags.tagName
                    }
                )
        }
    ).ToList();
```

*a list of all books that are associated with a particular tag*

```
var tagId=1;
var lsBooksByTagId=(
            from book in db.Books
            where
                (
                    db.BookHasTag.Where(a=>a.tagId==tagId).Select(a=>a.bookId)
                ).Contains(book.id)
            select new
            {
                book.id,
                book.author,
                book.title
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked a treat. Thanks for your help. Can I just ask though - will each of these run only one query against the db?

Comment: Yes they will. If you want to see the sql statement use linqpad [link](http://www.linqpad.net/) to translate the linq code. Maybe you can accept the answer then?